# Python 3.7.3, shutil import copy2 code not working correctly. How to fix?

Tags: python-3.x, copy, shutil

Another beginner question. This code was working fine for me yesterday. I can't think what has changed but can anyone spot what is going wrong?:

```
import shutil, os
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("D:\231019"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('Fused.tiff'):
            full_path = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
            new_path = os.path.join(folderName)
            shutil.copy2(full_path, new_path)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I keep being given the following in the shell:

```
>>> 
=========================== RESTART: D:\copyfil.py===========================  
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. In the above, the drive name only has a single backslash. Frustrating but glad I discovered it.